# How to define an array of functions in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, definition

I have a struct that contains a declaration like this one:

```
void (*functions[256])(void) //Array of 256 functions without arguments and return value
```

And in another function I want to define it, but there are 256 functions!
I could do something like this:

```
struct.functions[0] = function0;
struct.functions[1] = function1;
struct.functions[2] = function2;
```

And so on, but this is too tiring, my question is there some way to do something like this?

```
struct.functions = { function0, function1, function2, function3, ..., };
```

**EDIT**: Syntax error corrected as said by Chris Lutz.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> I have a struct that contains a declaration like this one:

No you don't. That's a syntax error. You're looking for:

```
void (*functions[256])();
```

Which is an array of function pointers. Note, however, that `void func()` isn't a "function that takes no arguments and returns nothing." It is a function that takes unspecified numbers or types of arguments and returns nothing. If you want "no arguments" you need this:

```
void (*functions[256])(void);
```

In C++, `void func()` *does* mean "takes no arguments," which causes some confusion (especially since the functionality C specifies for `void func()` is of dubious value.)

Either way, you should `typedef` your function pointer. It'll make the code infinitely easier to understand, and you'll only have one chance (at the `typedef`) to get the syntax wrong:

```
typedef void (*func_type)(void);
// ...
func_type functions[256];
```

Anyway, you can't assign to an array, but you can initialize an array and copy the data:

```
static func_type functions[256] = { /* initializer */ };
memcpy(mystruct.functions, functions, sizeof(functions));
```

Comment: Just note that the memcpy() is dangerous and non-portable, as a struct may contain any number of padding bytes. If you use memcpy() like shown here, you must verify that the compiler has no padding enabled. Typically through `assert(sizeof(the_struct.functions) == sizeof(functions))` or similar.

Comment: That's incorrect. `sizeof(some_struct)` returns the size of the structure + any necessary padding. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member) for example. The usage of `memcpy` above is correct.

Comment: ..and in this case, the `memcpy()` isn't being used on structs anyway - it's being used to copy from one array to another, of identical size, which is fine.  The fact that the destination array is a struct member is immaterial.

Comment: I probably should have noted that `struct` is a keyword, so using it as a variable name is wrong even for sample code that's never going to come near a compiler.

Comment: the difference between `func()` and `func(void)` is just a matter of `C++` not of C, is it?

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem, this is my small program to test the solution. It looks pretty straightforward so I thought I'd share it for future visitors.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}

int minus(int a, int b) {
    return a-b;
}

int multiply(int a, int b) {
    return a*b;
}

typedef int (*f)(int, int);                 //declare typdef

f func[3] = {&add, &minus, &multiply};      //make array func of type f,
                                            //the pointer to a function
int main() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) printf("%d\n", func[i](5, 4));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it dynamically... Here is a small example of a dynamic function array allocated with malloc...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void (*FOO_FUNC)(int x);

void a(int x)
{
    printf("Function a: %d\n", x);
}

void b(int x)
{
    printf("Function b: %d\n", x);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FOO_FUNC *pFoo = (FOO_FUNC *)malloc(sizeof(FOO_FUNC) * 2);
    pFoo[0] = &a;
    pFoo[1] = &b;

    pFoo[0](10);
    pFoo[1](20);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My bad... wrong context to this discussion... Instead, you could use typedef to define FOO_FUNC type, and then create a FOO_FUNC array and use the names as initializers...

Answer (score 1):

From the top of my head and untested.

```
// create array of pointers to functions
void (*functions[256])(void) = {&function0, &function1, &function2, ..., };

// copy pointers to struct
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) struct.functions[i] = functions[i];
```

**EDIT**: Corrected syntax error as said by Chris Lutz.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that while declaring your struct instance:

```
function_structur fs = { struct_field1,
                         struct_field2,
                         {function0, function1, ..., function255},
                         struct_field3,
                         ... };
```

You cannot use this shortcut for initialize arrays after the array has been declared: if you need to do that, you'll have to do it dynamically (using a loop, a `memcpy` or something else).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *post*-initialize an array using form like `{func1, func2, ...}`, this can be accomplished in the following way (using GCC):

**UPD** (thanks to [Chris Lutz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60777/chris-lutz) for remarks)

Define a macro like this:

```
#define FUNCTION_VECTOR_COPY(destVec, sourceVec) memcpy(destVec, sourceVec, sizeof(sourceVec))
```

And pass source vector using [Compound Literals](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1.1/gcc/Compound-Literals.html), as follow:

```
#include <string.h>
...
void (*functions[256])();
...
FUNCTION_VECTOR_COPY (functions, ((void(*[])()) {func1, func2, func3}));
```

Comment: `sizeof(funcsFrom)` is invalid here. Arrays in function parameters decay to pointers so your function is really `void setFuncs(void(**funcsTo)(), void(**funcsFrom)())` with no information about the `sizeof`. You should a) use a macro, which would allow you to do that, or b) pass the array size as a third parameter. And if you do b, you can even c) write a wrapper macro that automatically plugs in the third argument based on the `sizeof` the second. Furthermore, d)  use `sizeof(funcsFrom) / sizeof(funcsFrom[0])` in case the types change, and e) your function is otherwise identical to `memcpy`.

Comment: @Chris thanks for the vital remarks, I've tested for 2 values only, that why I missed `sizeof` issue. (a) - great!; (d) - ok, but you should check first if source vector has size greater than 0; (e) - yep, but you should not forget to include `string.h`. See updated answer.