# defining an array of C functions

Tags: c, arrays, function, definition

I've got a bunch of C functions which get assigned to an array of function pointers, along the lines of this:

```
typedef int (*func)(int);

int SomeLongName1(int a) {         
  // ...
}                      

// ...

int SomeLongName1000(int a) {         
  // ...
}                      

func f[] = { SomeLongName1, ... , SomeLongName1000 };
```

This is a lot of work to create and is prone to errors.  For instance, there could be a typo in the function name such that a valid function is still named, but the wrong one.  Or, if a new function is added at the end one could forget to go in and explicitly add it to the list of function pointers as well.

In order to avoid having to explicitly declare the array of function pointers I have tried various tricks such as macros, which make the code hard to understand and require knowing how the macro works, and I am generally unsatisfied with them.

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
typedef int (*func)(int);

func f[] = {             
  int SomeLongName1(int a) {         
    // ...
  }                      
  // ...                   
  int SomeLongName1000(int a) {         
    // ...
  }                      
};
```

This way, the array would be automatically created, and if there was some way to put a null pointer at the end so I can determine how many function pointers there are that would be great as well.

However, the above isn't valid C and I'm coming up empty with any way of accomplishing this.  If it is something compiler specific (e.g. a GCC extension) that would be ok.

All the functions are statically known at compile time, so I would like to avoid having to do any run-time initialization of the function pointer array - not that I have found a method to do it that way either.

This related question [How to define an array of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309859/how-to-define-an-array-of-functions-in-c), seems to ask the same question, but does not carry it to its logical conclusion.  Specifically, I don't want to have to re-type anything I have already typed so as to save time and avoid errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would use to solve such a situation (only if I can't avoid it, of course), is to use preprocessing. Not the one available from the C preprocessor, it does not provide the required functionality in a sensible syntax, but a really powerful one like `m4`.

With `m4`, your code could look like this:

```
define(`functionList', `, 0')
define(`functionArrayMember', `define(`functionList', `$1, 'FunctionList)$1')
define(`buildFunctionArray', `{ functionList }')

int functionArrayMember(SomeLongName1)(int a) {
    return a+1;
}
//...
int functionArrayMember(SomeLongName1000)(int a) {
    return a+1;
}

func f[] = buildFunctionArray();
```

You just need to provide the right `m4` definition for `functionArrayMember()` and `buildFunctionArray()`, and you have the functionality you need.

Comment: I really like this idea. Some kind of tutorial on how to use m4 in the context of a C program would be nice (no luck with Google so far...)

Comment: I have added the `m4` definitions that should do the trick. I have not tested it, though, so there might be a bug in it. The idea is, that the `functionList` macro accumulates the list of the function names, so that you can later dump them into the array literal.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful.  What is the recommended way of running C source through m4?  I am hoping that I can do it similar to the existing pre-processor, that is, without needing to retain the intermediary output of m4 for compilation.

Comment: Well, you could try to make a pipe out of `m4` and the compiler, you would just need to tell the compiler to read from stdin instead of from a file. I generally prefer to use an intermediate file, putting a rule in my Makefile to run `m4` on .c.m4 files to produce a .c file, and then a normal compilation rule. That way, I can easily debug the `m4` step by itself. In this simple case, that might not be that important, however, the stuff I have used `m4` for basically required it...

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about the order of functions in the array, and are willing to use a GCC extension, then you can achieve what you want using a whole bunch of initializer (constructor) functions. This obviously isn't ideal because of the sheer number of extra functions defined, but it is certainly one approach you can consider. It constructs the array at runtime.

Define the function `append` to append a single function to an array (reallocating if needed). Then, the code is basically

```
#define ARRAYFUNC(name) int name(int); \
    void __attribute__((constructor)) __init_##name(void) { append(func); } \
    int name(int a)

ARRAYFUNC(func1) {
    ...
}

ARRAYFUNC(func2) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Cool idea, let the linker figure out what belongs into the array. The nice thing is, that this will even work when the functions are not all defined in the same file. You got my vote :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the C preprocessor ([X-Macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)) for this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// define a list of function names and bodies
#define FUNCS \
  FUNC(add, { return a+b; }) \
  FUNC(mul, { return a*b; }) \
  FUNC(div, { return a/b; })

// let the preprocessor make up the actual function implementations
#define FUNC(name, body) int name(int a, int b) body
FUNCS
#undef FUNC

typedef int (*func)(int, int);

// let the preprocessor populate the array of function pointers
func f[] = {
#define FUNC(name, body) name, 
FUNCS
#undef FUNC
};

// use it:
int main () {
    int a = 2, b = 3, i = 0;
    for (; i < sizeof(f)/sizeof(*f); i++) {
        printf("%d\n", f[i](a,b));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
$ gcc test.c && ./a.out
5
6
0
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is any other way of doing what want to do.

What you wrote

```
func f[] = { SomeLongName1, ... , SomeLongName1000 };
```

already does what is best.

Maybe you could name your functions with an prefix 0000 to 1000, so that you can be sure each function is in the right place in your functions pointer array.

Also, if you really have 1000 different functions, they are surely things in common that could lead you to sort them in several arrays, reducing the numbering effort, and that is less error prone.